# How to use JS to check if divs have svg tags inside of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have this JS function that essentially cycles through some divs to see if there is a question mark side the div tags (which in my app means a question wasn't answered) and if it finds one, it displays a required message for that field and puts a red border around it to make it more noticeable.

```
  $( function() {
        //stuff to do on submit
        $('#add').submit(function() {
          const allFields = [ 'dob', 'tob', 'sex', 'weight'];

          allFields
            .forEach(nameOfField => {
              $(displayError(nameOfField)).hide();
              $(formField(nameOfField)).removeClass('error-border');
            });

          const listOfFieldsFailedValidation =
            allFields
              .filter(field => {

                //The two lines in question
                const fieldText = $('#' + field + '-display').text();
                return fieldText.indexOf('?') !== -1;

              });

          if (listOfFieldsFailedValidation.length <= 0)
            return true;

          $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 0);

          listOfFieldsFailedValidation
            .forEach(nameOfFieldFailedValidation => {
              $(displayError(nameOfFieldFailedValidation)).show();
              $(formField(nameOfFieldFailedValidation)).addClass('error-border');
            });

          return false;
        });

});
```

I have since edited my app to use SVG question marks inside the divs, instead of plain text question marks.

So now I need to check if a SVG tags exist in the divs, rather than checking if the text includes a "?".  I'd like to simply edit the "two lines in question" (noted in the code) to keep everything within this overall function.  is that possible?

I tried replacing the two lines in question with the following but no luck:

```
 const fieldText = $('#' + field + '-display');
 return fieldText.getElementsByTagName('svg').length > 0;
```

Can anyone help me correctly check to see if SVG tags exist, instead of a plain text question mark, all while using this same overall function?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is a native DOM method, `fieldText` is a jQuery collection. Either always use DOM methods or always use jQuery methods, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.  So I'm really just trying to keep using JQuery then (fieldText), just having trouble changing the existing to code to run the check on SVG tag instead of a text question mark.

Comment: `fieldText.find('svg').length`

Answer (score 1):

Using the [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

   var svg = $("div").find("svg");
   
   console.log(svg.length) // Outputs 7

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Or use a `CSS` selector inside the `jQuery` selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   
   // Or use a CSS selector
   var svg = $("div svg");
   
   console.log(svg.length) // Outputs 7

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```